# How to display XML content in HTML file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xslt, xml-parsing

This is my xml code . I want to display the contents in a html page with Javascript.

```
<businesses>
    <business bfsId="" id="41481">
        <advertHeader>Welding Supplies, Equipment and Service Business</advertHeader>
        <Price>265000</Price>
        <catalogueDescription>Extremely profitable (Sales £500k, GP £182k) business</catalogueDescription>
        <keyfeature1>
        Well established 25 year business with excellent trading record
        </keyfeature1>
        <keyfeature2>
        Consistently high levels of turnover and profitability over last 5 years
        </keyfeature2>
    </business>
    <business bfsId="" id="42701">
        <broker bfsRef="1771" ref="003">Birmingham South, Wolverhampton &amp; West Midlands</broker>
        <tenure>freehold</tenure>
        <advertHeader>Prestigious Serviced Office Business</advertHeader>
        <Price>1200000</Price>
        <reasonForSale>This is a genuine retirement sale.</reasonForSale>
        <turnoverperiod>Annual</turnoverperiod>
        <established>28</established>
        <catalogueDescription>This well-located and long-established serviced office</catalogueDescription>
        <underOffer>No</underOffer>
        <image1>https://www.business-partnership.com/uploads/business/businessimg15977.jpg</image1>
        <keyfeature1>other connections</keyfeature1>
        <keyfeature2> Investment Opportunity</keyfeature2>
        <keyfeature3>Over 6,000 sq.ft.</keyfeature3>
        <keyfeature4>Well-maintained </keyfeature4>
        <keyfeature5>In-house services &amp; IT provided</keyfeature5>
    </business>
</businesses>
```

This is the original xml file https://alpha.business-sale.com/bfs.xml   I have just took a short portion to describe the situation.

**Requirements**

- Print a row for every `<business>` element
- For every `<business>`  pick some specific child element and print column only for those element.( Not all ). For an example in this case I only want to print the value for `<advertHeader>` ; `<Price>` and `<description>` and want to ignore other elements.
- Only print the row those `<business>` where value of `<Price>`   is > 10000 . if it is then less than 10000 do not print that row
- pagination after every 10 row

This is the html table

```
<table id="MainTable"><tbody id="BodyRows"></tbody></table>
```

And this is the javascript code that i have tried .

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            getRows();
        });

        function getRows() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("get", "2l.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    showResult(this);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }

        function showResult(xmlhttp) {
            var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
            removeWhitespace(xmlDoc);
            var outputResult = document.getElementById("BodyRows");
            var rowData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("business");

            addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(rowData,outputResult);
        }

        function addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(xmlNodes,tableNode) {
            var theTable = tableNode.parentNode;
            var newRow, newCell, i;
            console.log ("Number of nodes: " + xmlNodes.length);
            for (i=0; i<xmlNodes.length; i++) {
                newRow = tableNode.insertRow(i);
                newRow.className = (i%2) ? "OddRow" : "EvenRow";
                for (j=0; j<xmlNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                    newCell = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);

                    if (xmlNodes[i].childNodes[j].firstChild) {
                        newCell.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    } else {
                        newCell.innerHTML = "-";
                    }
                    console.log("cell: " + newCell);

                }
                }
                theTable.appendChild(tableNode);
        }

        function removeWhitespace(xml) {
            var loopIndex;
            for (loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < xml.childNodes.length; loopIndex++)
            {
                var currentNode = xml.childNodes[loopIndex];
                if (currentNode.nodeType == 1)
                {
                    removeWhitespace(currentNode);
                }
                if (!(/\S/.test(currentNode.nodeValue)) && (currentNode.nodeType == 3))
                {
                    xml.removeChild(xml.childNodes[loopIndex--]);
                }
            }
        }
```

But this code prints columns for all the nodes under `<business>` element. And the number of child elements under `<business>` are different  . So the result comes like this
[image]

I dont want that. I want to only display the value of specific nodes under `<business>` element (in this case only include `<advertHeader>` ; `<Price>` and `<description>` ) so that the number of columns are equal in every row. How to do that?

Comment: Which browsers do you target? And as you use client-side XSLT and an HTML table, what kind of pagination do you have in mind?

Comment: @MartinHonnen All the regular browser i.e Chrome, Safari, firefox, ie.

Comment: Regarding pagination I dont have anything particular in mind. Ideally  To list 10 ro on each page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the `<business>`-element with the most values and build your table around that. Here's an example snippet that does that for the data you presented.

```js
{
  const xml = new DOMParser()
    .parseFromString(getData(), `text/xml`);
  
  // the <business>-elements from xml
  const businessElems = [...xml.querySelectorAll(`business`)];
  
  // the nodeNames will be the header. While we're at it,
  // we can count the number of headers (len) for later use
  const headersFromXml = businessElems.map( v => 
    [...v.querySelectorAll(`*`)]
      .map( v => v.nodeName) )
      .map( v => ( {len: v.length, headers: v} ) 
  );
  
  // now determine the longest header using a reducer
  const businessElemWithMostNodes = headersFromXml
    .reduce( (acc, v) => v.len > acc.len ? v : acc, {len: 0});
  
  // utility to create a tablecell/header and append it to a row
  const createCell = (rowToAppendTo, cellType, value) => {
    const cell = document.createElement(cellType);
    cell.innerHTML = value;
    rowToAppendTo.appendChild(cell);
  }
  
  // utility to create a datarow and append it to a table
  const createDataRow = (tableToAppendTo, businessElem) => {
    const row = document.createElement(`tr`);
    const rowValues = [];
    
    // create values using the businessElemWithMostNodes order
    businessElemWithMostNodes.headers
      .forEach( head => {
        const valueElem = businessElem.querySelector(`${head}`);
        rowValues.push(valueElem ? valueElem.innerHTML : `-`);
      });
    
    rowValues.forEach( v => createCell(row, `td`, v) );
    tableToAppendTo.appendChild(row);
  };
  
  // now we know enough to create the table
  const table = document.createElement(`table`);
  
  // the headerRow first
  const headRow = document.createElement(`tr`);
  businessElemWithMostNodes.headers.forEach( hv => createCell(headRow, `th`, hv) );
  table.appendChild(headRow);
  
  // next create and append the rows
  businessElems.forEach(be => createDataRow(table, be));
  
  // finally, append the table to document.body
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  
  // your xml string
  function getData() {
    return `
    <businesses>
      <business bfsId="" id="41481">
        <advertHeader>Welding Supplies, Equipment and Service Business</advertHeader>
        <Price>265000</Price>
        <catalogueDescription>Extremely profitable (Sales £500k, GP £182k) business</catalogueDescription>
        <keyfeature1>
          Well established 25 year business with excellent trading record
        </keyfeature1>
        <keyfeature2>
          Consistently high levels of turnover and profitability over last 5 years
        </keyfeature2>
      </business>
      <business bfsId="" id="42701">
        <broker bfsRef="1771" ref="003">Birmingham South, Wolverhampton &amp; West Midlands</broker>
        <tenure>freehold</tenure>
        <advertHeader>Prestigious Serviced Office Business</advertHeader>
        <Price>1200000</Price>
        <reasonForSale>This is a genuine retirement sale.</reasonForSale>
        <turnoverperiod>Annual</turnoverperiod>
        <established>28</established>
        <catalogueDescription>This well-located and long-established serviced office</catalogueDescription>
        <underOffer>No</underOffer>
        <image1>https://www.business-partnership.com/uploads/business/businessimg15977.jpg</image1>
        <keyfeature1>other connections</keyfeature1>
        <keyfeature2> Investment Opportunity</keyfeature2>
        <keyfeature3>Over 6,000 sq.ft.</keyfeature3>
        <keyfeature4>Well-maintained </keyfeature4>
        <keyfeature5>In-house services &amp; IT provided</keyfeature5>
      </business>
    </businesses>`;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font: 12px/15px normal consolas, verdana, arial;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thats really helpful. As you can see in the xml code the position of the child nodes are not similar as well. for the first <business>  node the fisrt child node is   <advertHeader> whereas for the second <business> node  <advertHeader> node is in the 3rd position. Hence in the result it can be confusing. How can I overcome that

Comment: @Bashabi That's a different question ;). In my answer the 'incomplete row-problem' is tackled. The node order may me solved by using `longest` and iterating through `business`-elements using a `querySelector` per node name from that

Comment: Well, it's not that difficult to keep the order, see revised code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In your example you passed the xml code as string. Is there any way I can pass that as a link . and get the content from that link. as my xml file is too long

Comment: "Is there any way I can pass that as a link?" Not in this (stackoverflow-) context, you have to figure that one out yourself, sorry. Maybe jsFiddle (https://docs.jsfiddle.net/external-resources) can help

Comment: You can safely remove the curly brackets: it's a way to create a (anonymous) namespace. Try experimenting with this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/r4f5kn6u/